# Going insane: Mysql query just won't work; yet very simple

Tags: php, mysql

```
//DB connect is here    

foreach ($find as $listing) {

    //bunch of hooblah that discovers $state and $city

    //this and below is all you need to see really
    $city = strip_tags($location_broken3[0]);
    $state = strip_tags($location_broken3[1]);
    print $city; //THIS WORKS...
    print $state; //AS DOES THIS!
    //tried this also
    $city1 = settype($city, 'string');
    $state1 = settype($state, 'string');
    $zip_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zip_codes WHERE city = '$city' 
        AND state = '$state' OR city = '$city' AND full_state = '$state'
    ") or die(mysql_error());
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($zip_query)) {
        die("<h1><b>Query Working!!</b></h1>");
    }
}
```

`$zip_query` is returning zero rows. The query works if I copy/paste it into phpmyadmin and replace the variables with their corresponding strings.

I've used this same exact structure on another page also, with the query inside the `foreach` (not efficient, I know) with same parameters. Column names are correct. Going crazy. Do you see an error?

Update:

To test the query on this php page I tried:

`$zip_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM zip_codes WHERE state = 'california'") or die(mysql_error());`

And it worked. Some of the $state variables = 'california'. Have tried both `strip_tags` and `mysql_real_escape_string`.

`var_dump` will return:

```
string(10) "California"
```

And the query fails. but if I manually enter `state = 'California'` the query works.

Comment: What variables does `$zip_query` contain and what happens if you run it in a database interface like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: It's up there where I commented

Comment: @Pekka not sure what you mean. I'm setting `$zip_query` on that line itself.

Comment: @Pekka I've done that and it works in phpmyadmin.

Comment: @user you're 1000% sure you are connecting to the same database?

Comment: Try assigning the string inside mysql_query to a variable and then dumping that value and running it in mysql query. Just to make sure that what you're checking is the actual value that is being generated.

Comment: @Pekka thank you yes. I include a connect file that I use for every other mysql script in this directory.

Comment: @JohnP Could you give an example of how to do that?

Comment: @user Didn't you say you did that already and it worked in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: No idea why I'm getting down voted for this. Still searching for a solution.

Comment: Not my downvote, but as said, the very first step in a case like this should be outputting the *exact query* that is being sent to the database. (using `echo`) You said to me you did that, and to JohnP that you did not.  Which is correct? Can you show the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing a `var_dump()` on `$city` and `$state` just before your query.

It could be that they are empty or have quotes in them or something.

Comment: Good idea. Tested it and no quotes or anything. I escaped it just to be sure also.

Comment: A mere syntax error in the variables being passed in the query was the cause of the problem. Although I checked, after double checking, there appeared to be outer trim outside of the city variable, causing the query to not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I guess here you made a mistake by omitting parenthesis:

```
"WHERE city = '$city' AND state = '$state' OR city = '$city' AND full_state = '$state'"
```

did you mean:

```
"WHERE city = '$city' AND state = '$state' OR (city = '$city' AND full_state = '$state')"
```

this can be simplified to:

```
"WHERE city = '$city' AND (state = '$state' OR full_state = '$state')"
```

Comment: Tested and did not work. Ready to rip eyes out.

Comment: are you sure you connect to the right database and not some different one then in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Thank you, yes. Absolutely 100%. Checked about 20 times since making this thread just to be sure. Instead of including my normal connect file I manually entered the connection parameters. Still failing with this script.

Answer (score 0):

do you get any error while you run it ?
there must be some mysql error if query is wrong.
try changing this a bit.

```
 $zip_query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM zip_codes WHERE city = \''.$city.'\' AND state = \''.$state.'\'  OR city = \''.$city.'\' AND full_state = \''.$state.'\') ;
```

also check if $city and $state etc are in proper case as in databse

Answer (score 0):

`full_state = '$state)"`

whats missing? :)

Answer (score 0):

I always like to put my SQL query into a format, so that I can log it or display it while debugging.

```
$fmt = 'SELECT * FROM zip_codes'
     . ' WHERE ( city = "%1$s" AND state = "%2$s" )'
     . '  OR ( city = "%1$s" AND full_state = "%2$s" )';

$query = sprintf($fmt, $city, $state);
print "<br/>DEBUG: query = <tt>$query</tt><br/>\n";
$result = mysql_query($query);
...
```

Then if you're still wondering, test your query (as shown by the debug line) in the MySQL command line.

Answer (score 0):

You should use mysql_real_escape_string to escape your values and not strip_tags:

```
$city = mysql_real_escape_string($location_broken3[0]);
$state = mysql_real_escape_string($location_broken3[1]);
```